# ¿Cómo ignorar un valor Nan en un sumatorio?

Tags: python

Me gustaría hacer un sumatorio de una lista que contiene un valor nan sin que el resultado final me salga nan. Por ejemplo:

```
a = [float('nan'),1,2,3]
b = sum(a)
```

Y que el resultado sea 6, en vez de nan. Es decir, que al hacer el sumatorio simplemente ignore el valor nan, sin asignarle otro valor o cambiar la longitud de la lista.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la función `math.isnan(x)` para revisar si un valor `x` es `nan` o no.

Comparar `x == float('nan')` siempre retorna `False`, incluso si `x` fue asignado con `float('nan')`.

Para hacerlo en forma concisa, se usa una comprensión de lista con el agregado de consultar si el elemento es un valor válido antes de agregarlo a la nueva lista.

#### Demo

```
import math

a = [float('nan'),1,2,3]
b = sum([x for x in a if not math.isnan(x)])
print(b)
```

produce:

```
6

Process finished with exit code 0
```